# Interview for 2 positions with 1 company. 1 offer 1 still waiting

Tags: interviewing

I'm looking for advice. Last week I interviewed for 2 jobs. Both these jobs are with the same company, just at two different locations. The position that is my second choice, has offered me the job. My first choice said I would hear "early this week" but I have not heard anything as of yet.

Since it is for the same company, would it be okay to state I am waiting on the status of the other job I applied for? I just would hate to take the second choice and then get an offer from what would  be my first choice.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Is there any overlap as far who's involved in the decision making process for the two positions? Is "this week" in "early this week" Jan 6 2020 to Jan 12 2020?

Comment: I interviewed last week and should her "early this week" meaning this week we are on no. They is zero overlap, the only overlap would be that the same HR would be sending me the job offers. It's a large company with many locations.

Answer (score 3):

I think in most cases it's good to be forthcoming about the fact that you're waiting for another offer. It's as good a reason as any to postpone giving them an answer and usually the company will be understanding and allow you some time. It may not always be a good idea to say what the other offer is but in your case, since it's the same company, I don't see any down side.

I *would* avoid mentioning that the other job is your first choice. You don't want to give the impression that you're anything less than 100% enthusiastic. Just tell them that you want to weigh your options before making a decision. Having multiple offers on the table can help provide leverage in salary negotiation as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Since it is for the same company, would it be okay to state I am waiting on the status of the other job I applied for?

I see no problem with that, although don't mention that they are your first option as the other answer suggests (as that could give a bad impression).

I must also note that it is barely Monday/Tuesday (depending on your location) at the moment of posting this answer, so it is *still* "early this week". Your response is surely about to arrive, so perhaps consider giving it a couple more days before assuming something went wrong with their response.

Comment: Oh, I don't feel like something went wrong. I know it's still early in the week. I just have an offer on the table that I don't want to lose in case the other doesn't work out.

Comment: I see... did the second option give you a time limit for you to take the offer? If they did you have that time window to wait for your first option's response, before committing to the second option.

Comment: No I have not gotten a time frame. I have been stalling it asking questions. But I feel like since it's now the end of the day, out of respect, I should say something about what is going on.